# Change text .net maui icon bar

Tags: maui

I'm trying to figure out how to set the window title so it shows the name of the application next to the Icon at the bottom bar on windows machines. If you have a browser window open, at the bottom, you'll see that window with the browser logo and some text. I have been able to change the Icon but I'm unsure of how to add text next to the icon for my .net maui application.

I was able to change the icon by going into the .csproj file and updating the  property.

I'd like my app to look like this with my logo and some text:
[image]

Comment: Your description is a little bit vague. Could you please elaborate your question clearly? Or show some code or image on what you have achieved and things on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not real sure how to explain it. You know on the windows task bar how it shows your open programs with the application logo and text. So if you had Chrome or Edge open, at the bottom where the start button is you'd see the chrome logo and the name of the page. I've changed the logo but how do I show text.

Comment: Please help add some images or pictures on how you changed the logo. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the update. Looks like you want to change the maui app icon with text in the windows task bar. I think this can be only modified in the windows system level. For MAUI, you can only change the app icon.

Comment: Right, that is what I was explaining I am trying to do... Do you have any examples on how one does this with the text?

Comment: Consider googling it on how to add the maui app icon with text in the windows task bar.